# Generating public-private key pairs where determining the public key is also hard to calculate if unknown

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, private-key, bitcoin

I'd like to know how one would go about generating a private-public key pair where the public key is as hard to deduce from the private key as visa versa?

As I understand it presently the exponent part of the public key is left deliberately simple so that the private key can be used to generate the public key.

My interest in this is to create no-trusted-third party escrow execution using Bitcoin. This raises the second question of whether this is possible using the Bitcoin protocol?

Comment: The math of RSA does not require a small public exponent. But the whole notion of public key crypto involves a private and a *public* key, so it isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please elaborate on your "no-trusted-third party escrow" concept. Also note that you may wish to split this into two questions, with the first question posted at http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ and the implementation part posted here.